# How to make rounded corners not rectangle

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to make a corner like the picture below.

[image]

At first, I created 4 layers and proceeded to draw rounded corners with a path like the picture below

[image]

However, this method gave up because the lines were not drawn smoothly

Second, I tried to implement it using a mask.

[image]

but,contrary to my expectations, masking was applied like the below picture.

[image]

How can I makeit masking like the first picture?

my code is

```
func makeGuideline() {
        let roundedRectangleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let roundedRectangleWidth = frame.width * 0.6
        let roundedRectangleHeight = frame.height * 0.4
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (frame.width / 2 - roundedRectangleWidth / 2), y: (frame.height / 2 - roundedRectangleHeight / 2)), size: CGSize(width: roundedRectangleWidth, height: roundedRectangleHeight)), cornerRadius: 10)
        
        roundedRectangleLayer.path = path.cgPath
        roundedRectangleLayer.fillColor = .none
        roundedRectangleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        roundedRectangleLayer.lineWidth = 1
        
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let maskPath = UIBezierPath()
        let maskWidth = roundedRectangleWidth * 0.2
        let maskHeight = roundedRectangleHeight * 0.3
        
        maskPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2 - maskWidth / 2, y: frame.height / 2 - roundedRectangleHeight / 2))
        maskPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2 - maskWidth / 2 + maskWidth, y: frame.height / 2 - roundedRectangleHeight / 2))
        
        maskLayer.fillColor = .none
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
        maskLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        maskLayer.lineWidth = 1
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        roundedRectangleLayer.mask = maskLayer

        layer.addSublayer(roundedRectangleLayer)
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path ( pun intended :)

First, instead of having a `makeGuideline()` function, I recommend adding the shape layer when the view is initialized and then updating the path / mask in `layoutSubviews()`. That will keep the shape / size updated if/when the view frame changes.

In addition, in `layoutSubviews()` we can use the `bounds` property instead of the frame.

Second, we can save some awkward `frame.width / 2 - maskWidth / 2` stuff by taking advantage of `.insetBy()` method of `CGRect`.

For example... if we want the rounded-rect frame to be 60% of the width and 40% of the height of the view, we can do this:

```
// make the "lines" frame
//  width: 60% ... inset by 20% on each side
//  height: 40% ... inset by 30% on top/bottom
let roundedRectFrame = bounds.insetBy(dx: bounds.width * 0.2, dy: bounds.height * 0.3)
```

Let's start with a view controller:

```
class GuideLineTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    let guideLineView = GuideLineView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)
        
        guideLineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(guideLineView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            guideLineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            guideLineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            guideLineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            guideLineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),
        ])

        // let's make the custom view light cyan, so we can see its frame
        guideLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
    
}
```

and a "basic" `GuideLineView`:

```
class GuideLineView: UIView {
    
    private let roundedRectShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        roundedRectShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        roundedRectShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        roundedRectShapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        layer.addSublayer(roundedRectShapeLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // make the "lines" frame
        //  width: 60% ... inset by 20% on each side
        //  height: 40% ... inset by 30% on top/bottom
        let roundedRectFrame = bounds.insetBy(dx: bounds.width * 0.2, dy: bounds.height * 0.3)
        
        let roundedRectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundedRectFrame, cornerRadius: 10.0)
        roundedRectShapeLayer.path = roundedRectPath.cgPath
    }
    
}
```

which gives us this:

[image]

To get only the corners to show, we need to mask the "inner" parts of the lines.

So, we'll use `.insetBy` on the rounded corner rect frame to define horizontal and vertical overlapping rectangles:

```
    // define a "horizontal" rectangle
    //  just a little wider (to exceed the line width)
    //  height: 50% ... inset by 25% on top/bottom
    let hRect = roundedRectFrame.insetBy(dx: -(roundedRectShapeLayer.lineWidth * 2.0), dy: roundedRectFrame.height * 0.25)
    
    // define a "vertical" rectangle
    //  just a little taller (to exceed the line width)
    //  width: 50% ... inset by 25% on each side
    let vRect = roundedRectFrame.insetBy(dx: roundedRectFrame.width * 0.25, dy: -(roundedRectShapeLayer.lineWidth * 2.0))
```

the red-dashed lines show those rectangles, which is what we want to mask:

[image]

If we use that as-is though... only the part of the rounded-rect line covered by red will "show":

[image]

and we get this:

[image]

Of course, not the goal.

So, we need to "invert" the mask. To do so, we'll create rectangular `UIBezierPath` that covers the full view, append the overlapping rectangles, use even-odd fill rule:

[image]

Again, only the red-covered parts will show, so our end result is:

[image]

Here's the complete custom view:

```
class GuideLineView: UIView {
    
    private let roundedRectShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        roundedRectShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        roundedRectShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        roundedRectShapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
        layer.addSublayer(roundedRectShapeLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // make the "lines" frame
        //  width: 60% ... inset by 20% on each side
        //  height: 40% ... inset by 30% on top/bottom
        let roundedRectFrame = bounds.insetBy(dx: bounds.width * 0.2, dy: bounds.height * 0.3)
        
        let roundedRectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundedRectFrame, cornerRadius: 10.0)
        roundedRectShapeLayer.path = roundedRectPath.cgPath
        
        // define a "horizontal" rectangle
        //  just a little wider (to exceed the line width)
        //  height: 50% ... inset by 25% on top/bottom
        let hRect = roundedRectFrame.insetBy(dx: -(roundedRectShapeLayer.lineWidth * 2.0), dy: roundedRectFrame.height * 0.25)
        
        // define a "vertical" rectangle
        //  just a little taller (to exceed the line width)
        //  width: 50% ... inset by 25% on each side
        let vRect = roundedRectFrame.insetBy(dx: roundedRectFrame.width * 0.25, dy: -(roundedRectShapeLayer.lineWidth * 2.0))
        
        // rectangle path covering the full view
        let fullMaskPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        
        // append the horizontal rectangle
        fullMaskPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: hRect))
        
        // append the vertical rectangle
        fullMaskPath.append(UIBezierPath(rect: vRect))
        
        // this will "invert" the mask
        fullMaskPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
        // create a layer to use as a mask
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        // must also be set on the layer using the inverted path
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        
        maskLayer.path = fullMaskPath.cgPath
        
        roundedRectShapeLayer.mask = maskLayer
        
    }
    
}
```

Because the rounded-rect is just an outline, we don't care that the center overlap of the vertical and horizontal rectangles will show through. If that mattered, instead of appending the rectangles we could use them for a series of `.addLine(to: pt)` to create the shape.